# How to add Custom component in Denali's (Sql Server 2012) toolbox?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

For the first time ever, I have created a custom Data flow component that will simply convert any string in UpperCase. I was very excited to find my custom component working but has been disappointed by the fact that, in the SSIS toolbox option there is no provision for adding the custom componenets to the toolbox.

As of now my point of reference is [Adding Custom Components to SSIS](http://agilebi.com/mcole/2009/08/18/adding-custom-components-to-ssis/)

Is there any way to solve this issue or I am missing something or is it a as of now bug in Denali's SSIS?

Comment: If it's not working the usual way, I'd guess they are working on the functionality.  Have you tried searching the books online/msdn?  I'm looking now, but having a hard time...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the manual page on what you are trying to do:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403356%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx

Found this article on creating an installer - might work.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/04/how-to-create-an-installer-for-your-custom-extension.aspx
But then there is a link to a connect item at the end - so it seems like this method doesn't actually work - it will do everything aside from adding it to the toolbox.

Comment: I have seen both the links but they are still not upto denali.. the toolbox option is missing the Custom tool menu